# Laplace transform of trig + Heaviside

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, laplace-transform

So I am trying to take the laplace transform of $\cos(t)u(t-\pi)$. Is it valid for me to treat it as $((\cos(t)+\pi)-\pi)u(t-\pi)$ and treat $\cos(t)-\pi$ as $f(t)$ and use the 2nd shifting property, or is this not the correct procedure? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach:

$$\mathcal{L}(\cos(t)) = \dfrac{s}{s^2+1}$$

$$\mathcal{L}\{\cos(t)u(t-\pi)\} = e^{-\pi s}\mathcal{L}(\cos(t-\pi)) = e^{-\pi s}\mathcal{L}(-\cos(t)) = -e^{-\pi s} \dfrac{s}{s^2+1}$$

Recall from the sum formula:

$$\cos(t - \pi) = \cos t \cos \pi + \sin t \sin \pi = -\cos t$$

Comment: I bet! Good luck! You're almost there! (Well, not quite, but it will be over before you know it, and you'll end up enjoying it, once you get going!)

Comment: Convincing perfect way. :+)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\cos(t) = \cos((t-\pi) + \pi) = -\cos(t-\pi)$.

Hence, $$\mathcal{L}\{\cos(t)u(t-\pi)\} = -\mathcal{L}\{\cos(t-\pi)u(t-\pi)\} = \ldots$$

Comment: Why is $\cos((t-\pi)+\pi)$ = -$\cos(t-\pi)$?

Comment: Use the trig identity $\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta$ where $\alpha = t-\pi$ and $\beta=\pi$.